# Lowercase to uppercase vowels C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to solve a problem where I am given a string of lowercase characters and I have to convert the vowels to uppercase.
(`e.g. : "mother" becomes "mOthEr".`)

**My attempt**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char s[20];
int i;

int main()
{
    cin.getline(s,20);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='a'||s[i]=='e'||s[i]=='i'||s[i]=='o'||s[i]=='u')
            s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
    }
    cout<<s;
}
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong? I got **Wrong Answer** on one of the tests.

Comment: What if the string is longer than 20 chars? (like Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious)

Comment: Can you show the test that you fail, and your output?

Comment: Your code is a very bad mix of C and C++. Either use proper C or C++, but don't mix them like this.

Comment: @hellow That's not really very helpful advice, as I would guess that they are a beginner who simply doesn't yet know what is good or bad practice. Especially as many teachers try to teach C++ by first teaching C.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the problem states that the string has a maximum of 20 characters.Regarding the test I fail,I can't see its input because the website where I encountered this problem doesn't let you see the tests.

Comment: Maybe it is, but I'm afraid the comment section does not leave room for a good explanation. I try it: char[20] is bad. You can store up to 19 chars (the 20th is the `\0` terminator) and you can very easily read above the limit. Use `std::string` instead :) Have a look at the example of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline to use getline with a string to read any length.

Comment: is `y` a vowel, too?

Comment: @hellow thank you,the size was the problem.

Comment: Relevant once again: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Comment: If your string is less than 20 characters, you still convert 20 characters.  See `std::strlen`.

Comment: Was is something like "Elephants are cool" ? (We need to know what input failed.)

Comment: If your string is max 20 chars, you need array the size of 21 to accommodate terminating `\0`;

Answer (score 2):

First, as already stated, you are confining the code to a maximun of 20 characters while you can make it more fluid and allowing for variable length by using `std::string` and `std::getline()`. You can do that by using the string length function `i < input.length()`.

variable `i` is declared as a global which is an overkill.

You also need to let the user know what to do; if run as stated, the console will look blank and unless you wrote the program, you have no idea what is going on. You need something like `cout << "Enter Line to modify: ";` to instruct the user to type something.

Spacing and proper naming convention is something that you need to start doing from day one as to become second nature. Can't tell you how many hours I have wasted trying to figure out what the programmer is using variables for that have names like a, b, cc, and so. Give all your variables meaningful names, you will thank me in the future.

Comment: The auto formatting on this page is killing me. I wanted to show:   input.length();

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string input;
    cout<<"Enter Line to modify:"<<endl;  
    getline(cin,input);
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i]=='a'||input[i]=='e'||input[i]=='i'||input[i]=='o'||input[i]=='u')
            input[i]=toupper(input[i]);
    }
    cout<<input<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: use the tick mark "`" to get inline code style.  To get block code style, indent everything by 4 spaces.

Comment: Use ` for inline Code. Also: Why don't you edit your answer instead writing comments to it?

Comment: Swordfish - I tried multiple times to edit the answer to no avail. That is why I try the comment route. Thanks to Ben for the link. Just started here so I need to learn the ropes.